# Setting Up HTML 5 Data Attribute Value Using CSS

Tags: css, html, attributes, overwrite, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to set/overwrite HTML 5 `data-` attribute value using CSS? For example for an `<img>` tag we can overwrite its width and height attributes via CSS properties but I don't know how to do the same with HTML 5 attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no you can not. CSS is not meant to process data in any way. It is just for styling.